# react bootsrap element not centering

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a "div" that was centered horizontally, then updated to use react bootstrap "
form".

Now the elements on the "form" are not centered, appearing to the left...

[image]

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-title">
                Countdown to {this.state.deadline}
            </div>
            <Clock
                deadline={this.state.deadline}
            />
            <Form inline>
                <FormControl 
                    className="Deadline-input"
                    placeholder='new date' 
                    onChange={event => this.setState({newDeadline: event.target.value})}
                />
                <Button onClick={() => this.changeDeadline()}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}
```

All is under className App

```
.App {
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
margin-top: 20%;
}

.App-title {
font-size: 50px;
}

.Clock-days,
.Clock-hours,
.Clock-minutes,
.Clock-seconds {
display: inline;
margin: 10px;
}

.Deadline-input {
font-size: 25px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Why it is not centered anymore? how to align my form on the center?
:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` bootstrap adds some styles and classes by default to the elements, Because of this form, it is folded to the left.

You can just add `justify-content-center` class to `<Form inline />`

```
<Form inline className="justify-content-center">
```

**like this:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-title">
                Countdown to {this.state.deadline}
            </div>
            <Clock
                deadline={this.state.deadline}
            />
            // add justify-content-center class to the <Form />
            <Form inline className="justify-content-center">
                <FormControl 
                    className="Deadline-input"
                    placeholder='new date' 
                    onChange={event => this.setState({newDeadline: event.target.value})}
                />
                <Button onClick={() => this.changeDeadline()}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}
```